# Bootcamp assistant cannot partition drive

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition

I am trying to install Windows 10 1809 via bootcamp assistant on my 2016 MBP and it keeps showing me the following error:

[image]

Here is the output from diskutil list:

```
Carsons-MBP:~ carsonclark$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.7 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.7 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            21.1 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 68.7 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.0 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US... +5.1 GB     disk2
```

Here's my disk utility:

[image]

And I've tried the following:

- Using disk utility to scan/repair disk
- Reinstalling MacOS

The following terminal commands:

- diskutil verifyvolume / diskutil repairvolume
- /sbin/fsck -fy

I'm not sure what else to try. FileVault is off by the way.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try adding the output from `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0` and `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0` to your output. You need to disable SIP to run the commands.

Comment: See the question [Cannot partition w/ Boot Camp Assistant on macOS Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354694/cannot-partition-w-boot-camp-assistant-on-macos-mojave)