# Cannot partition w/ Boot Camp Assistant on macOS Mojave

Tags: bootcamp, partition, mojave, apfs

Late 2016 Macbook Pro running Mojave 10.14.3, APFS-formatted (ugh).

I have run Disk Utility to verify my disk, and I've run `fsck -fy` from single-user mode several times. Both of these have reported absolutely no errors.

And yet, whenever I try to run Boot Camp Assistant to dual-boot with Windows 10, I get an error that says: "An error occurred while partitioning the disk."

Thinking I'd be clever, I also tried to create a partition manually through Disk Utility, but that didn't work either. I also reinstalled macOS in Recovery Mode.

I am starting to suspect that this is a problem with APFS. What other commands could I run to receive more information as to why Boot Camp Assistant won't let me create a partition to run Windows? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret trick was running `fsck_apfs -o -y`. ‍♂️

Comment: How did you come up with this answer? It would seem the `-o` option is undocumented.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I just ran the command and noted that that option was in the output.

Comment: `-o` is only available for `fsck_apfs` since over provisioning is an APFS related issue to be addressed. so the correct and accepted answer should be `fsck_apfs -oy`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is called overallocation. The following helped me to fix it on Mojave APFS:

Please note, there is a lot of posts out there telling you to do `fsck`. If you are on APFS you need to do `fsck_apfs` instead. This is what made the difference for me.

1. Shut down your Mac.
2. Start and hold <kbd>Cmd-S</kbd> to boot into single user mode.
3. Run `fsck_apfs -o`
4. It will ask you to confirm, type in y and press Enter.
5. When finished (up to 3 minutes) type `reboot` and press Enter.

After trying everything I could find, this finally worked.

I also ran `fsck_apfs -n -l` before I ran `fsck_apfs -o` but I don't think that made any difference.

As I watched the results it produced this line:
`Overallocation detected on Main device`
And then it did:
`Fix overallocation`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem , i did reinstall mac os (Mojave) but problem not resolved.
Finally i solved using this.

- Restart your mac and Pressed **`Command + S`** to boot into single user mode.
- Type **fsck_apfs -y /dev/disk0s2** and hit enter
- If you can see some questions type **y** and hit enter
- After all you can see like as **appear OK**
- Type **reboot** and hit enter

  ***your problem is solved !***